# How to remove/alter search results from Linux Mint start menu?

Tags: debian, ubuntu, linux-mint, search, menu

Linux Mint 18.0 Cinnamon Edition has a start menu, which can quickly be launched with the `windows key`. Typing thereafter brings up search results, which have a functional or descriptive relation to the typed content. This is something the vast majority of users is aware of.

I often use this to quickly launch folders, files or programs. For instance, typing

```
windows key + "goo" + enter
```

launches Google Chrome on my PC, since this would be the closest match.

But this doesn't always work as I intend, for example typing

```
windows key + "dow" + enter
```

[image: LM Start Menu Search "dow"]
would launch "Effects", when I actually want to launch the Download folder.

The search is not wrong - there are good reason for all the shown results - but if I type "dow", I *always* want to launch the Download folder.

**QUESTION:** Can I somehow adjust which results are shown/hidden for certain typed strings? If not, is there any other possibilty to change the behaviour of the search to above described liking? I have no problem to manually type somewhere

```
"dow" --> /home/username/downloads
"lalala" --> libreoffice
...
```

I value the intelligence of the LM search, so I don't want to break it. There are just specific moments when I know what I want, and LM doesn't.

Comment: I bet you are annoyed with "calc" ---> "libraoffice calc" instead of "calculator" :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just found your question after asking myself the same thing. I found out that if you:

- Right click menu
- Configure...
- Select menu tab
- Open menu editor

Here you can edit all the entries. Cinnamon order all found applications by their name so you can either rename them to something further down the alphabet (e.g. "Advanced REST Client" to "REST Client") or add a space in front of those that you want to have come up first in your search.

Additionally there are some files under /usr/share/applications and /usr/local/share/applications that seem to store various information about the applications but editing them (with root) didn't seem to change anything, but maybe it gives someone a thing to explore further so I wanted to include that here.

Comment: I upvoted it (not yet shown) because your find is useful, and with your tip I made a shortct to my Downloads folder (Adding a new Item with the name "Dow" and the command "nemo Downloads").
But it isn't quite what I was looking for, so I leave the question open.

Comment: Very effective ! Now I prepend `a myApp` to my favorite apps for they appear first, magic! Hope there will be a feature where the search order by preference / last used next version * - *